# ERROR TypeError: Set.prototype.delete is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, set

Не могу удалить объект из Set-а. Ошибка ERROR TypeError: `this.user.roles.delete is not a function`
Моя функция

```
removeRole(userid: number, roleid: number) {
    this.users.forEach((u) => {u.id === userid ? this.user = u : u; });
    this.user.roles.forEach((role) => {role.id === roleid ? this.user.roles.delete(role) : role; } );
    this.userService.update(this.user).subscribe((perf) => {
        this.user = perf;
        this.toast.success('Permission deleted', 'cloud-upload-outline');
      },
      err => {
        this.toast.error('Something gone wrong', 'cloud-download-outline');
      });
  }
```

Модель User.ts

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password?: string;
  roles: Set<Role>;
  profile: Profile;
  documents?: Set<Document>;
  positions?: Position[];
  contacts: Contacts;
  additional: Additional;
}
```

До этой функции выводил user-а в `console.log()`, правильно выводит. В чем может быть ошибка? Гуглил, но не нашел ответа. Думаю делаю очень простую ошибку, так как результат поиска только одна подходящая ссылка.

Comment: Также делал не используя тернарные операторы, обычным if else. Такая же ошибка

Comment: А вы уверены что в момент обращения к функции там именно Set? Посмотрите через отладчик, объект какого именно типа там используется

Comment: *До команды `this.user.roles.delete(role)` выводил user-а, выводит правильно. user существует

Comment: @andreycrane в Intellij idea ссылается на Set<Role>

Comment: Я имею ввиду поле user'а roles. Вероятно что в процесс исполнения программы там ссылка на объект другого типа, у которого в прототипе нет указанного метода

Comment: Извините если я буду Вас злить). (property) User.roles: Set<Role> показывает что это Set. Далее нажимаю на .delete придерживая **Ctrl** перенаправляет _lib.es2015.collection.d.ts_ `interface Set<T> {
    add(value: T): this;
    clear(): void;
    delete(value: T): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, value2: T, set: Set<T>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    has(value: T): boolean;
    readonly size: number;
}`

Comment: Это описание типа может быть недостоверным. IDE показывает вам что будет в процессе исполнения гипотетически. Если на практике, во время запуска возникает эта ошибка, значит IDE ошибается. Если на то пошло, что в проекте используется TypeScript, то проверьте проект на ошибки.

Comment: Поставьте там точку останова и посмотрите в отладчике реальное значение ссылки, а не то что вам показывает autocomplete hint

Comment: Поставил точку, в Chrome-> Sources-> Debugger-> Scope->Local-> user-> roles: Array(1) Показывает так. Получается он стал Array?

Comment: Да, именно в этом и проблема. Не видя как именно создается этот объект, сложно сказать почему там именно массив, а не Set, как вы описали в типе класса. Но проблема отсутствия метода именно в этом.

Comment: `users: User[] = [];` `user: User;` так я декларировал массив user-ов и user-a перед тем как тянуть с базы. Может ли это быть причиной конвертации Set-a в Array. Если да, как можно правильно декларировать?

Comment: Когда вы извлекаете данные из БД они преобразуются в массив. Вам нужно либо самостоятельно, либо с использованием ORM определить в какие значения JS будут транслироваться данные из БД и наоборот.

Comment: Действительно, все преобразовывается в массив. Хотя в backend-e я передаю dto где все в Set-ах. И модель user-а в front-e тоже в Set-ах. А посередине когда я делаю subscribe -> принимаю data -> приравниваю user = data то все становиться Array. Пока не знаю как это изменить...

Answer (score 0):

Как отметил в комментариях @andreycrane Set после запуска преобразовывался в Array. Поэтому функции Set-a не применялись.

> Когда вы извлекаете данные из БД они преобразуются в массив. Вам нужно либо самостоятельно, либо с использованием ORM определить в какие значения JS будут транслироваться данные из БД и наоборот. – @andreycrane

Изменил Set на Array

```
        this.roles = [...user.roles];
        const index = this.roles.findIndex(n => n.id === roleid);
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.roles.splice(index, 1);
        }
```

Хотя когда использую переменную в IDE показывает как ошибку, но все работает.

Comment: @andreycrane спасибо!